# How to get focus on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two EditText boxes editText1 and editText2 and I'm trying to give input to those edit boxes by using softkeybord. After entering values to editText1 and pressing back (i.e closing the softkeybord) from devise backpress button, the focus in automatically get changed to editText2 and cursor is blinking on editText2 . I don't want to this to be happen, I want focus to be on editText1. Any idea how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you can do it.

```
edit.requestFocus();
```

where edit will be the edit text for with you want to set the focus.

Comment: Thanks for your response Akki, i tried this also its not working.

Comment: might be something in java code if you could show me that possibility would be high to resolve the issue you have